# Getting 2 Images to Drag in View Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, drag-and-drop

I have 2 images in a view and I applied a drag touch function to the images, and when the image collides with the image at the top of the view it gives you an alert and changes the image at the top of the view to a different image.

My problem is getting my if else statement to work, If i take out the == image in

```
([touch view] == image) {
```

Only one of the images drag, I cannot seem to get both images to drag. My if else statement has no errors, but does not seem to work.

**frfViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface frfViewController : UIViewController {
UIImageView *image;
UIImageView *image2;
UIImageView *images;
UIImageView *collisionImage;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *collisionImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *images;
@end
```

**frfViewController.m**

```
#import "frfViewController.h"

@interface frfViewController ()

@end

@implementation frfViewController

@synthesize image;
@synthesize image2;
@synthesize images;
@synthesize collisionImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

//      [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
//      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if ([touch view] == image) {

    image.center = location;
    image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


}

else if ([touch view] == image2) {

    image2.center = location;
    image2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}

[self ifCollided];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
[self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void) ifCollided {
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(image.frame, collisionImage.frame) ||  CGRectIntersectsRect(image2.frame, collisionImage.frame)) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"image Collided"
                                                    message:@"FuckYea"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Reset!"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
    images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
    [images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"004.jpg"]];
    [self.view addSubview:images];
 }


}

@end
```

[image]

Thanks any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 4 and up you can use UIPanGestureRecognizer to do dragging easily,

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(labelDragged:)];
 [yourview addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

Add recognizer to each UIView and set selector to point, where you set new coordinates = where you can limit it , if you get collision for example...

```
- (void)labelDragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)gesture.view;
CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:label];

// move label , limit it to stay inside self.view.frame
float newx = label.center.x + translation.x;
float newy = label.center.y + translation.y;

if (newx<0) { newx = 0; }
if (newy<0) { newy = 0; }

if (newx>self.view.frame.size.width) {
    newx = self.view.frame.size.width;
}

if (newy>self.view.frame.size.height) {
    newy = self.view.frame.size.height;
}

//possibly compute collision here and limit new coordinates further

label.center = CGPointMake(newx,newy);

// reset translation
[gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:label];
}
```

Also have a look at draggable&resizable View class at https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView , that may save you a bit of work also